# TFS Create Branch from Branch Error "the item does not exist at the specified version or you do not have permission to access it"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I have a Saas type web app, and currently have no branches. I want to have a Dev and a Main branch. I had all my project folders just under the main TFS project folder. I then created a Dev folder and moved all the sub project folders and files into it since the current code represents the latest future work compared to what is currently in production. Now I am trying to create the Main Branch from the Dev branch by the changeset that represents the current production environment.

But when now trying to branch from the Dev branch, it says that

`$/Project/Dev does not exist at the specified version or you do not have permission to access it`

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to convert the Dev branch to just a folder and try again (I would try it but afraid of messing something up)? Reparent the Dev branch? Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when doing a branch by Label and the labeling was not on the same level (node) as the branch itself. Situation in TFS:

```
branch     <-- branch
  folder1
  folder2  
    folder <-- label
```

If you do a find in the "find label" dialog it's on a global level and not in the branch you selected. So in this sample folder1 is not part of the label. In our case the labeling is performed by a release build that does a get on folder2 instead of the branch. That's why things are this way. The error message is not very clear.

Maybe you got the same issue, where the changeset is not part of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. In my case I created a label for a file $/EDA/Source/Integration/ETL/RunLoad.fex using tf command line utility and using the same tf command line utility ran the branch command to create a branch from $/EDA/Source/Integration/ to $/EDA/Source/Prod/Release1 and got this error. To resolve this issue what I ended up doing is during the label creation using tf command I did create a label for the folder $/EDA/Source/Integration/ first and then to the file $/EDA/Source/Integration/ETL/RunLoad.fex using label merge option. This took care of the issue and I am able to create a branch using a label now.